# Add specific text in every blank line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, sed, awk

I've a file as below

```
abc

pqr
xyz


aaa
bbb

ccc
```

I want to add specific text like "this is test" in every blank line like below

```
abc
this is test
pqr
xyz
this is test
this is test
aaa
bbb
this is test
ccc
```

Help me to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the regex for empty line is `^$`, using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^$/this is test/' file 
abc
this is test
pqr
xyz
this is test
this is test
aaa
bbb
this is test
ccc
```

Using `awk`, you can rely on the number of elements `NF`. If this one is `0` then set the line `$0` to the wanted string:

```
$ awk '!NF{$0="this is test"}1' file
```

Comment: Could also be written as: `awk '/^$/ {$0="this is test"}1' file`. Perl equivalents: `perl -lape 's/^$/this is test/' file` or `perl -lape '$_="this is test" if !$_' file`.